# Aumentar la memoria de Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos

Buenas noches estimados, tengo un problema que aun no puedo encontrar una solucion me gustaria que puedan ayudarme; la cuestión es la siguiente estoy tratando de aumentar la memoria para apache tomcat, he revisado otros foros y me dicen que modifique el archivo catalina.sh, la cuestión es que ese archivo no existe en Apache Tomcat 7, me recomendaron modificar el archivo ubicado en la siguiente dirección /var/cpanel/tomcat.options (Centos 6), el archivo lo creé porque no existía en la dirección probé agregando la siguiente linea:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Pero me generó error al reiniciar apache tomcat

probe solo con:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

y de igual forma me seguia generando error; revise los log y me lanza lo siguiente:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m
>   -Xmx1024m"
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:151)

Por favor alguien me puede indicar si esta bien la ruta en la que estoy agregando el comando o es de otra forma, se les agradece de antemano.

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré esta forma de establecerlo en el archivo

sudo nano /opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh && sudo chmod +x /opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx7168M"